# How to update DOM after getting user location in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, geolocation

I am making a web application which requires user's location.

I've also included dropdown with pre-filled cities. When the page loads, the default city is selected.

```
<div>
    <select class="form-control" ng-model='city.selected' required ng-options='option.value as option.name for option in citiesOptions' ng-change="cityChange()"></select>
</div>
```

Controller

```
$scope.citiesOptions = [
    { name: 'NY', value: 'New York' },
    { name: 'Chicago', value: 'Chicago' },
    { name: 'Minneapolis', value: 'Minneapolis' },
    { name: 'San Francisco', value: 'San Francisco' }
];
if($rootScope.usercity == null){
    $scope.city = {
        selected : $scope.citiesOptions[0].value
    };
    window.localStorage.setItem('usercity', $scope.citiesOptions[0].value);
    $rootScope.usercity =  window.localStorage.getItem('usercity');
}
else{
    $scope.city = {
        selected : $rootScope.usercity
    };
}

$scope.cityChange = function(){
    console.log('City Has Changed');
    console.log($scope.city.selected);
    window.localStorage.setItem('usercity', $scope.city.selected);
}
```

After page load, user is asked to share his/her location, if successful, we get their location city and store it in local storage.

Now we compare the selected location city with user location city, if they are different, I want to update the DOM and show items related to the user location city.

```
$scope.checkCity = function(){
    if($rootScope.usercity != $rootScope.userlocation && $rootScope.userlocation != ''){
        console.log('Cities are different, so choosing User City');
        window.localStorage.setItem('usercity', $rootScope.userlocation);
    }
}
```

I've managed to compare the two results but cannot figure out how to update the page with new location.

Comment: just assign updated value to your model. Nothing else..

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious way is to:

- first, change the city.selected in your scope
- second, ngChange won't be fired because the input was not changed, it was model change. So fire the cityChange manually, do whatever you have to do(update DOM, display stuff, preferably calling other functions) in the cityChange function.